# Can I express the square of a random variable in terms of its variance?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, covariance

when I have a random variable $x$ with variance $\sigma^2$, is it possible to express $x^2$ in terms of its variance $\sigma^2$ (and other terms)?

I would like to change the expression $\text{Cov}_t(y_{t+1},x^2_{t+1})$ to something like $\text{Cov}_t(y_{t+1},\sigma^2_{t+1})$.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random variable cannot be reduced to its variance, since that is just a moment of the distribution.  However, if $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mu_X$, $\mathbb{V}(X)=\sigma_X^2$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mu_Y$ then you can write:

$$\mathbb{Cov}(X^2,Y) = \mathbb{E}(X^2 Y)-\mathbb{E}(X^2)\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(X^2 Y)-(\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2)\mu_Y.$$

Answer (score 0):

If, x = [1,2,3,4,5]
Variance of x = 2.5

Variance is a single number. There lies your problem, covariance is between two vectors, but variance is only a single number for a vector.

An alternate way you can look at it is through the use of z-scores. Here, the value of Z is practically the distance of a point from a mean in terms of its standard deviation, not variance.

Not sure if either is what you want. However, what you've stated doesn't seem like it is possible.